# Table doesn't show the information in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, angular-material

The information displays in console but when I try to display the information in the table, the columns show but not the objects.

[image: angular table]

Here is the code:

product-list.component.html page =

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Product Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ProductName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductStock">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Stock </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ProductStock}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductPrice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ProductPrice}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CreatedDateTime">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CreatedDateTime}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ModifiedDateTime">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Updated Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ModifiedDateTime}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                   showFirstLastButtons
                   aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

product-list.component.ts page =

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['ProductName','ProductStock','ProductPrice','CreatedDateTime','ModifiedDateTime'];
  dataSource : MatTableDataSource<product_list> = null
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator : MatPaginator;

  async ngOnInit() {
  
      this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.BallBits);

     const productsAll : product_list[] = await this.productService.productList(() => this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallBits), error => this.alertify.message(error, {
        messageType : MessageType.Error,
        position : MessagePosition.TopRight
      }));
      
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<product_list>(productsAll);
      

  }
```

Does someone know what is my error?